# Create all combinations of 4 elements out of a larger list

Tags: bash, python, permutation

I want to create all possible combinations of 4 chemical elements out of a list of 9 and use them to create folders named after these combinations.
The desired list looks something like this:

{Cr, Hf, Mo, Nb, Ta, Ti, V, W, Zr}

What I want to get out of it, would be:

CrHfMoNb

CrHfMoTa

CrHfMoTi

CrHfMoV

...

TiVWZr

and so on for all 126 possible arrangements, stored in a list or something similar so that I can use it as input for creating the folders. These combinations should be ordered alphabetically, so that Hf always comes after Cr and before Ti for example.
I can use both Bash and Python, I prefer the simpler method. If the method could easily be adapted to a different number like combinations of 5 that's a big plus.

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  The programming part of your question (generating all combinations, sorting elements) is off-topic.  Using the resulting list to create directories is on-topic, but already has an answer in eg. [What is the fastest way to create a list of directories specified in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174326/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-list-of-directories-specified-in-a-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has "itertools" which includes a function to perform these kind of combinations for you.

```
combinations('ABCD', 2)  returns    AB AC AD BC BD CD
```

so you could do something like...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import itertools
output = []
for i in itertools.combinations(['Cr', 'Hf', 'Mo', 'Nb', 'Ta', 'Ti', 'V', 'W', 'Zr'], 4):
        output.append("".join(i))
print(sorted(output))
```

Which would produce all 126 combinations and sort them for you.

```
['CrHfMoNb', 'CrHfMoTa', 'CrHfMoTi', 'CrHfMoV', 'CrHfMoW', 'CrHfMoZr', 'CrHfNbTa', 'CrHfNbTi', 'CrHfNbV', 'CrHfNbW', 'CrHfNbZr', 'CrHfTaTi', 'CrHfTaV', 'CrHfTaW', 'CrHfTaZr', 'CrHfTiV', 'CrHfTiW', 'CrHfTiZr', 'CrHfVW', 'CrHfVZr', 'CrHfWZr', 'CrMoNbTa', 'CrMoNbTi', 'CrMoNbV', 'CrMoNbW', 'CrMoNbZr', 'CrMoTaTi', 'CrMoTaV', 'CrMoTaW', 'CrMoTaZr', 'CrMoTiV', 'CrMoTiW', 'CrMoTiZr', 'CrMoVW', 'CrMoVZr', 'CrMoWZr', 'CrNbTaTi', 'CrNbTaV', 'CrNbTaW', 'CrNbTaZr', 'CrNbTiV', 'CrNbTiW', 'CrNbTiZr', 'CrNbVW', 'CrNbVZr', 'CrNbWZr', 'CrTaTiV', 'CrTaTiW', 'CrTaTiZr', 'CrTaVW', 'CrTaVZr', 'CrTaWZr', 'CrTiVW', 'CrTiVZr', 'CrTiWZr', 'CrVWZr', 'HfMoNbTa', 'HfMoNbTi', 'HfMoNbV', 'HfMoNbW', 'HfMoNbZr', 'HfMoTaTi', 'HfMoTaV', 'HfMoTaW', 'HfMoTaZr', 'HfMoTiV', 'HfMoTiW', 'HfMoTiZr', 'HfMoVW', 'HfMoVZr', 'HfMoWZr', 'HfNbTaTi', 'HfNbTaV', 'HfNbTaW', 'HfNbTaZr', 'HfNbTiV', 'HfNbTiW', 'HfNbTiZr', 'HfNbVW', 'HfNbVZr', 'HfNbWZr', 'HfTaTiV', 'HfTaTiW', 'HfTaTiZr', 'HfTaVW', 'HfTaVZr', 'HfTaWZr', 'HfTiVW', 'HfTiVZr', 'HfTiWZr', 'HfVWZr', 'MoNbTaTi', 'MoNbTaV', 'MoNbTaW', 'MoNbTaZr', 'MoNbTiV', 'MoNbTiW', 'MoNbTiZr', 'MoNbVW', 'MoNbVZr', 'MoNbWZr', 'MoTaTiV', 'MoTaTiW', 'MoTaTiZr', 'MoTaVW', 'MoTaVZr', 'MoTaWZr', 'MoTiVW', 'MoTiVZr', 'MoTiWZr', 'MoVWZr', 'NbTaTiV', 'NbTaTiW', 'NbTaTiZr', 'NbTaVW', 'NbTaVZr', 'NbTaWZr', 'NbTiVW', 'NbTiVZr', 'NbTiWZr', 'NbVWZr', 'TaTiVW', 'TaTiVZr', 'TaTiWZr', 'TaVWZr', 'TiVWZr']
```

If you want them "neatly" just use...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import itertools
output = []
for i in itertools.combinations(['Cr', 'Hf', 'Mo', 'Nb', 'Ta', 'Ti', 'V', 'W', 'Zr'], 4):
        output.append("".join(i))

while output:
        print(output.pop(0))
```

which gives...

> CrHfMoNb CrHfMoTa CrHfMoTi CrHfMoV CrHfMoW CrHfMoZr CrHfNbTa CrHfNbTi
>   CrHfNbV CrHfNbW CrHfNbZr CrHfTaTi CrHfTaV CrHfTaW CrHfTaZr CrHfTiV
>   CrHfTiW CrHfTiZr CrHfVW CrHfVZr CrHfWZr CrMoNbTa CrMoNbTi CrMoNbV
>   CrMoNbW CrMoNbZr CrMoTaTi CrMoTaV CrMoTaW CrMoTaZr CrMoTiV CrMoTiW
>   CrMoTiZr CrMoVW CrMoVZr CrMoWZr CrNbTaTi CrNbTaV CrNbTaW CrNbTaZr
>   CrNbTiV CrNbTiW CrNbTiZr CrNbVW CrNbVZr CrNbWZr CrTaTiV CrTaTiW
>   CrTaTiZr CrTaVW CrTaVZr CrTaWZr CrTiVW CrTiVZr CrTiWZr CrVWZr HfMoNbTa
>   HfMoNbTi HfMoNbV HfMoNbW HfMoNbZr HfMoTaTi HfMoTaV HfMoTaW HfMoTaZr
>   HfMoTiV HfMoTiW HfMoTiZr HfMoVW HfMoVZr HfMoWZr HfNbTaTi HfNbTaV
>   HfNbTaW HfNbTaZr HfNbTiV HfNbTiW HfNbTiZr HfNbVW HfNbVZr HfNbWZr
>   HfTaTiV HfTaTiW HfTaTiZr HfTaVW HfTaVZr HfTaWZr HfTiVW HfTiVZr HfTiWZr
>   HfVWZr MoNbTaTi MoNbTaV MoNbTaW MoNbTaZr MoNbTiV MoNbTiW MoNbTiZr
>   MoNbVW MoNbVZr MoNbWZr MoTaTiV MoTaTiW MoTaTiZr MoTaVW MoTaVZr MoTaWZr
>   MoTiVW MoTiVZr MoTiWZr MoVWZr NbTaTiV NbTaTiW NbTaTiZr NbTaVW NbTaVZr
>   NbTaWZr NbTiVW NbTiVZr NbTiWZr NbVWZr TaTiVW TaTiVZr TaTiWZr TaVWZr
>   TiVWZr

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this now and with both of your codes I get the error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the last line. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: @And when you do it exactly the same? Or have you nested it within some code of your own? In which case please show us :) Edit: Just ran it on an ubuntu VM in Python 3.5. Still works for me!

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7 and the first one does not work for me (I copied it). But with your updated change the second variant works (which is also more useful to me). Thank you!

Comment: @And glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 2):

Not as short as the python method, but still straightforward. Create a shell array and cycle through that in four `for` loops yielding the desired 126 lines:

```
ELARR=(Cr Hf Mo Nb Ta Ti V W Zr)
for ((i=0; i<${#ELARR[@]}; i++))
    do  for ((j=i+1; j<${#ELARR[@]}; j++))
          do    for ((k=j+1; k<${#ELARR[@]}; k++))
                  do    for ((l=k+1; l<${#ELARR[@]}; l++))
                          do    echo ${ELARR[i]}${ELARR[j]}${ELARR[k]}${ELARR[l]}
                          done
                  done
          done
    done
CrHfMoNb
CrHfMoTa
CrHfMoTi
CrHfMoV
CrHfMoW
.
.
.
TaTiWZr
TaVWZr
TiVWZr
```

Will be even shorter if you assign the array's element count to a variable, and use that, and mayhap use a shorter array name...